# Category image not showing product page in Magento 2

Tags: magento, slider, product, magento2, categories

I am facing a very strange issue. 
I have featured product slider on Magento homepage. When I click on the product from slider its shows different image / not showing any image. 
But if I open the same product by going into the category from the menu then it shows the category image in product.

Strangely if I refresh the same product from slider again it starts showing a correct image.

Please suggest what can I do.

**example:**

**step -1 :**

1) open this link https://www.teecloset.com/

2) go to featured product slider and click on first product of "animate" category i.e ANI-DP

It won't show any category image or would show incorrect image.

**step -2**

1) Now keep that tab open. From the main menu -> tees -> animate -> ANI-DP

now you will see yellow image as category image.

2) go back to previous tab and refresh. Now it loads the correct image.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

so this behavior is normal as it depends on the referrer. I think your approach is not the best. Did you think about custom layout for your products of special categories to get the header image?

As I see you have Animate, Beard, Gas Masks, Robot and Geometric - so you could easily create 5 layouts it think.

Another approach would be creating an product attribute with custom extension and block which shows an image based on the attribute value.